# Is "on January first" is also correct?

Tags: dates

If I want to express the date: 1/1/17 can I say "on January first"?

For example:

> I'm going to meet him on **January first**.

I know that I can say also: "the first of January", but my question is about the style that I showed.

Answer (score 6):

Month names do **not** take the definite article except when you're concerned to distinguish a particular month from other months of the same name (e.g., *the January when we had such warm weather--was that 1980 or 82?*).

A day-of-month designator expressed as an ordinal number (*first*, *second*, *third*, &c) ***may*** take the definite article if it follows the month name, and ***must*** take the definite article if it is the head of the date expression:

So:

> *on January the first*
>   *on January first*
>   *on the first of January* are all acceptable, but
>
> *on the January first*
>   *on the January the first*
>   *on first of January*
>   *on the first of the January*
>   *on first of the January*  are all unacceptable.

Comment: Way to cover all the combinations!

Comment: I think a few of the "unacceptable" examples are valid in referring to particular Januaries or January the firsts, just it is rare that this will be needed.

Here's an attempt at an example. "On the January first when the monsoon struck, I forget the year, we ..."

Answer (score 2):

Each of the following is acceptable, however, if you are in Britain, *January first* is *not* acceptable (although Americani(z)sation has taken its toll).

> on January the first;
>   on the first of January;
>   or
>   on January first

So, your example sentence is correct:

> I'm going to meet him on January first.

Comment: Then what is acceptable in Britain?

Comment: My other two examples, *first of January* or *January the first*.